# Why doesn't this simple JavaScript increment and decrement method work?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
(function() {
    var count = {
        digit: 0,
        increment: function() {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                if (++count.digit == 10) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    count.decrement();
                }
                var update = document.getElementById("liveUpdate");
                update.innerHTML = count.digit;
            }, 500);
        },
        decrement: function() {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                if (--count.digit == -1) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    };
    count.increment();
})();
```

It stops but it doesn't go down? What could be the problem?

Comment: Your code is correct, but you forget to display the `digit` in the `update` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `decrement` function never updates the output anywhere. The variable *is* going down but you don't show that on screen.

Try (or check the corresponding [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UMcsj/)):

```
(function() {
    var update = document.getElementById("liveUpdate");
    var count = {
        digit: 0,
        increment: function() {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                if (++count.digit == 10) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    count.decrement();
                }
                update.innerHTML = count.digit;
            }, 500);
        },
        decrement: function() {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                if (--count.digit == -1) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
                update.innerHTML = count.digit;
            }, 500);
        }
    };
    count.increment();
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

setInterval will call the function every 500 seconds. It will not stop until you stop it. You can read more about stopping it at [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

It't not a bug, it's a feature ;-). `setInterval()` runs the given function in a loop with a given interval (500 ms). See this [article](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval) for details.