# How to disable timer?

Tags: javascript, ajax, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop setInterval call in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

I use `window.setInterval` method for polling progress status. But need to disable this timer when it completed. How to disable timer?

```
      window.setInterval(function(){$.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'imports',
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response['status'] != 'ok'){
              return;
            }

            $('.bar').css('width', response['progress'] + '%');

            if(response['step'] == 'completed') location.reload();
      }}, 'json');}, 1000);
```

Comment: Probably duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/109086/1947535

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) is a really good JS reference if you're not sure how a particular function works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start the interval it returns an integer defining it:

```
var timer = window.setInterval( ... );
```

You can then clear that interval when your AJAX function returns true:

```
...
success: function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  if (response['status'] != 'ok') {
    clearInterval(timer);
    return;
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

the `setInterval()` method will return an integer/number. You need to store this, then pass it to the method `clearInterval()` to stop it.

```
var intervalId = window.setInterval(.....);
```

then later, when you want to stop it, I think it would go:

```
window.clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval()` returns a handle which you can later pass to `window.clearInterval()` to stop the timer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = window.setInterval(...);
// ...
window.clearInterval(x);
```