# Stop setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

I want to stop this interval in the `error` handler from running repeatedly. Is that possible, and if so, how?

```
// example code
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    setInterval(updateDiv,3000);
});

function updateDiv(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getContent.php',
        success: function(data){
            $('.square').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            $.playSound('oneday.wav');
            $('.square').html('<span style="color:red">Connection problems</span>');
            // I want to stop it here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Answer (score 268, accepted):

You need to set the return value of `setInterval` to a variable within the scope of the click handler, then use `clearInterval()` like this:

```
var interval = null;
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    interval = setInterval(updateDiv,3000);
});

function updateDiv(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getContent.php',
        success: function(data){
            $('.square').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            clearInterval(interval); // stop the interval
            $.playSound('oneday.wav');
            $('.square').html('<span style="color:red">Connection problems</span>');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Links to docs: [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) and [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: You could also use `setTimout()` which only runs once

Answer (score 25):

Use a variable and call `clearInterval` to stop it.

```
var interval;

$(document).on('ready',function()
  interval = setInterval(updateDiv,3000);
  });

  function updateDiv(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'getContent.php',
      success: function(data){
        $('.square').html(data);
      },
      error: function(){
        $.playSound('oneday.wav');
        $('.square').html('<span style="color:red">Connection problems</span>');
        // I want to stop it here
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 12):

You have to assign the returned value of the `setInterval` function to a variable

```
var interval;
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    interval = setInterval(updateDiv,3000);
});
```

and then use [`clearInterval(interval)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) to clear it again.

Answer (score 8):

USE this i hope help you

```
var interval;

function updateDiv(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getContent.php',
        success: function(data){
            $('.square').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            /* clearInterval(interval); */
            stopinterval(); // stop the interval
            $.playSound('oneday.wav');
            $('.square').html('<span style="color:red">Connection problems</span>');
        }
    });
}

function playinterval(){
  updateDiv(); 
  interval = setInterval(function(){updateDiv();},3000); 
  return false;
}

function stopinterval(){
  clearInterval(interval); 
  return false;
}

$(document)
.on('ready',playinterval)
.on({click:playinterval},"#playinterval")
.on({click:stopinterval},"#stopinterval");
```

Answer (score 3):

we can easily stop the set interval by calling clear interval

```
var count = 0 , i = 5;
var vary = function intervalFunc() {
  count++;
      console.log(count);
    console.log('hello boy');  
    if (count == 10) {
      clearInterval(this);
    }
}

  setInterval(vary, 1500);
```

Comment: Very bad practise. 1st this *could* mean thet `setInterval` could leak indefinetely - no var associated, to control it. 2nd you acn't clear on `this`, since `this` is not a time interval. If you use `TypeScript` you would got in trouble: `No overload matches this call.Overload 1 of 2, '(intervalId: Timeout): void', gave the following error: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Timeout'.`

Answer (score -2):

```js
var flasher_icon = function (obj) {
    var classToToggle = obj.classToToggle;
    var elem = obj.targetElem;
    var oneTime = obj.speed;
    var halfFlash = oneTime / 2;
    var totalTime = obj.flashingTimes * oneTime;

    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        elem.addClass(classToToggle);
        setTimeout(function() {
            elem.removeClass(classToToggle);
        }, halfFlash);
    }, oneTime);

    setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }, totalTime);
};

flasher_icon({
    targetElem: $('#icon-step-1-v1'),
    flashingTimes: 3,
    classToToggle: 'flasher_icon',
    speed: 500
});
```

```css
.steps-icon{
    background: #d8d8d8;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 55px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flasher_icon{
  color: #fff;
  background: #820000 !important;
  padding-bottom: 15px !important;
  padding-top: 15px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"> 

<i class="steps-icon material-icons active" id="icon-step-1-v1" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Origin Airport">alarm</i>
```

Comment: Please explain what this code does and how it's related to the question.