# jQuery add class to current li and remove prev li automatic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is my HTML code, I want to remove `active` class from 1st `li` and add it to 2nd `li` and viceversa automatic every 2 second using jQuery.

```
<li class="">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="client_logo01.png">
    </a>
</li>

<li class="active">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="client_logo02.png">
    </a>
</li>
```

I'm trying to do in this way.

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    $('ul li.current').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

But it is only working on click event.

Comment: you can use setInterval(setClass, 2000);

Comment: @Bokdem "vice versa" means "the other way around"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty obvious it only get's executed on click, as you only bound a click event..

```
setInterval(function()
{
    // Remove .active class from the active li, select next li sibling.
    var next = $('ul li.active').removeClass('active').next('li');

    // Did we reach the last element? Of so: select first sibling
    if (!next.length) next = next.prevObject.siblings(':first');

    // Add .active class to the li next in line.
    next.addClass('active');
}, 2000);
```

Run this on document ready and the script alters the active class onto the next sibling every 2 seconds.

**this runs regardless of the number of li children your ul element has**

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kg4huLrL/2/

Comment: what if `$('ul li.active')` is last `li`?

Comment: Bhushan: I've updated my answer to skip to the first element as soon as the last was active. jsfiddle ought to be working now :)

Comment: @Dennis Perfectly nice :), this is what I wanted. Thanks. Bhushan your answer is also good. but when I add new `li` it is not working.

Comment: @SumitBijvani try to be absolutely complete in your requirements next time, this might save the people whom answer some guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : remove `active` class from `li` with `active` class and put `active` class to its sibling `li`

```
   setInterval(function(){
       var $active = $('ul li.active');
       $active.removeClass('active');
       $active.siblings().addClass('active');
   },2000);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0meffmav/1/)**

Comment: This will add a .active class to áll siblings, might not be expected behaviour. Also: try and chain your calls; http://stackoverflow.com/a/25545165/1088868

Comment: @DennisJamin, This " want to remove active class from 1st li and add it to 2nd li and viceversa" says only two `li` present and OP want to toggle class between these two `li`

Comment: Fair ehough, your sollution however is not future- and waterproof. Mine however is more strict and covers all bases.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use setInterval, see this posting on how to use it:

[Stop setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437173/stop-jquery-setinterval)

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
    if($('ul').find('li.active').eq(0).next('li') != undefined) {
        $('ul').find('li.active').eq(0).removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('ul').find('li.active').eq(0).removeClass('active');
        $('ul').find('li').eq(0).addClass('active');
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Why use a .each? Quite cluttery code, as this might be solved by just selecting the right item using a .active selector..