# How can I stop a page from refreshing after a certain amount of time javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my page to reload every so often, but if a user is inactive for say 5 minutes I want to stop the page from reloading. I have an example on http://codepen.io/tetonhiker/pen/gLeRmw .

Right now it's refreshing every 10 seconds. Again I want it to stop say after 5 minutes of refreshing when a user is inactive. How can I do this?

```js
var timer = null;
$(function() {
  // Get the time to stop the effect
  var stopTime = new Date();
  stopTime.setMinutes(stopTime.getMinutes() + 5);
  // Get a reference to the timer so it can be cancelled later
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    // Check to see if the timer should stop
    var currentTime = new Date();
    if(currentTime  < stopTime){ 
      var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      $('#show').text(
        'I am getting refreshed every minute..! Random Number ==> '  + randomnumber);
    } else {
      // Stop the timer
      clearInterval(timer); 
    }
  }, 60 * 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show" align="center"></div>
 
    <div align="center">

    </div>
```

Comment: It might be more clear if you change your wording to be 'updating the contents of the show' rather than saying reload or refresh, which is usually associated with a browser action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437173/stop-setinterval)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set a variable equal to the timer id and cancel when your condition is met:

```
var timer = null;

// As soon as the document is ready:
$(function() {
   // Activate the timer:
   startClock();
});

// And, when the user interacts with the page, start over
$(document).on("mousemove click", function(){ 
  // Stop the previously running timer
  clearInterval(timer);

  // Start the clock over again:
  startClock();
});

function startClock(){
  // Get the time to stop the effect
  var stopTime = new Date();
  stopTime.setMinutes(stopTime.getMinutes() + 5);

  // Get a reference to the timer so it can be cancelled later
  timer = setInterval(function() {

    // Check to see if the timer should stop
    var currentTime = new Date();
    if(currentTime  < stopTime){ 
      var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      $('#show').text("I am getting refreshed every 10 seconds..! " +
                      "Random Number ==> " + randomnumber);
    } else {
      // Stop the timer
      clearInterval(timer); 
    }
  }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: how could I reset the timer once a user is active again?

Comment: You could extract all the code inside the `document.ready` function (the first function in the sample) into its own named function. This way, you can call that function, by name, again at any point that you wish.

Comment: So just break up the first function into it's own and then from timer = setInterval have it be it's own function? And then call the first function within the second one?

Comment: Can you define for me what "once a user is active again" means?

Comment: When the user has made a mouse movement or clicked something on the page.

Comment: @Teton-Coder See my updated answer with comments to address your current question.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in a couple different ways.  First I am going to assume you already have logic existing to check if a person has been idle for 5 minutes (as that makes answering this easier, :D)

What you can do is when you call setInterval, store it's result in a variable.  At which point if the user becomes idle for 5 minutes, window.clearInterval(thatVariable) to end the loop.

Otherwise, change your logic to use setTimeout instead and have it recursively call itself so long as the user has not been idle for 5 minutes.

Comment: It looks like you are doing the clearInterval route.  What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: How could I get it to reset once a user is active again?

Comment: Ah, well if you want to do that I would suggest putting that whole logic in a method.  And then in the event that the user is active again you can call that method to start the whole process over again.

Comment: any hints or tips on how to get that method started? Thanks for your help as well, much appreciated.

Comment: You'd just call whatever method you stuck it in.  If you put it in a method like function refreshShowText () { ... }  then later when they go from inactive to active you'd just call refreshShowText()

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () { 
      location.reload();
    }, 60 * 1000);
</script>
```

[setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) will [reload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) the page after a specified number of milliseconds, hence 60 * 1000 = 1m. Also, since the page is being refreshed, the timeout will always be set on page load.

Comment: He's not doing a reload.  He is 'refreshing' the content of '#show'.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is mix `setInterval` with `setTimeout`.

```
function refresh() {
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    $('#show').text('I am getting refreshed every 10 seconds..! Random Number ==> ' + randomnumber);
}

var intervalId = setInterval(refresh, 10 * 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    alert('refresh stop!');
}, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```