# jQuery let finish and then stop functions when tab loses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my code i've got a situation like this:

```
var t = setInterval(function(e) {
     if (document.hasFocus()) {
          // Tab Has Focus so,
          // Execute some actions 
      }
},4000);
```

I've a jQuery interval that every 4 seconds execute some actions. Like animate objects and adding css classes to my DOM.

The problem is that when i change tab ('blur' window event) and then re-add the focus event are re executed.

Is there a method that let the current actions finish and then stop the interval and then resume when page is focused?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437173/stop-setinterval

Comment: Sorry, i didn't add the last part of the question. I also need to resume the interval when i add focus to the tab

Comment: Is it a specific number of iterations.  Are these iterations defined in some way?

Comment: there're not a specific number of iterations, it's a constant loop that i need to stop/resume(with letting him finish his current action first) when i lose focus to a tab,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without your entirety of code.  I cannot give you an exact solution.
So, this may not be exactly what you're looking for.
But it's got a similar concept.
Maybe even more than what you actually need:

```
        var i = 0; // Track the iteration we are currently in.
        var t; // Used to set and clear intervals.

        function timer() {
          t = setInterval(function(e) {
            // Whereas I keep track of Iterations, you may wanna keep track of specific styles, etc...
            console.log(i);
            localStorage.setItem('currentIteration', i);
            i++;
        },1000);}
        timer();

        $(window).focus(function() {
            // If localStorage is set, continue from where we left off.
            var currentIteration = localStorage.getItem('currentIteration');
            if ( currentIteration != "" ) {
              i = ( Number(currentIteration) + 1 );
            }
            timer();
        });

        $(window).blur(function() {
            // You could command the css application to finish on tab leave.
            // Although, it should already finish, since it's a function already in progress.
            clearInterval(t);
        });
```

Comment: actually reminds somehow of singleton pattern. I like your solution

Comment: Thank you, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

A little [google around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript) would help, but here is what I found

```
var t = setInterval(function(e) {
     if (document.hasFocus()) {
          // Tab Has Focus so,
          // Execute some actions 
      } else {
          // if not in focus
          // stop the interval
          clearInterval(t);
      }
},4000);
```