# 'setInterval(function()' stopping

Tags: javascript

I wonder if it actually is possible to stop function explicitly, after using setInterval on it.

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){document.write("Hello");},1000);
</script>
```

Comment: please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval) :

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
      document.write("Hello");
      if (someCondition) {
         clearInterval(timer); // this stops the interval
      }
},1000);
```