# How can I cancel a function call that's inside an interval in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code here (with some lines removed to make it more clear). When a user clicks an edit icon the editRow() function is called and this opens a model window. After this the code tries to save data every second by calling factory.submitItem. Everything works okay except if there's a problem saving the data.

How can I make this so that if factory.submit item entityResource.update fails then the intervals are cancelled and the code stops doing a save every second.

```
     var factory = {

        gridSetup: function ($scope) {
            $scope.editRow = function (row, entityType) {
                // modal stuff happens here
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    window.setInterval(function () {
                        factory.submitItem($scope, $scope.modal.data);
                    }, 1 * 60 * 1000);
                    factory.submitItem($scope, $scope.modal.data);
                }, 1 * 60 * 1000);
            }
        },

        submitItem: function ($scope, formData) {
            var idColumn = $scope.entityType.toLowerCase() + 'Id';
            var entityId = formData[idColumn];
            switch ($scope.modal.action) {
                case "edit":
                    var entityResource = $resource('/api/:et/:id', { et: $scope.entityType }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
                    entityResource.update({ id: entityId }, formData,
                        function (result) {
                            angular.copy(result, $scope.modal.data);
                        }, function (result) {
                            // what to put here ?
                        })
                    break;
            }
        },
```

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval()` returns an interval ID, which you can pass to clearInterval():

```
var yourInterval = setInterval(function(), time);
```

You can cancel it with:

```
clearInterval(yourInterval);
```

Comment: that's luck much better than my answer XD

Answer (score 2):

```
myInterval = window.setInterval(function () {
    .....
}, 1 * 60 * 1000);
```

and when you want to cancel....

```
window.clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something diferent to do that. The scheme could be like this:

```
var everythingIsOk = true;

function doSomething(){
    if (everythingIsOk) {
        setTimeout(doSomething(),5000);
    } else {
       everythingIsOk = false;
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer but we are looking for a solution that uses are existing code. What we just need is some way to stop the iterations if there is failure with the auto update.