# Stop setInterval and start it again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this set interval function:

```
    function ticker(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $('.slide').fadeToggle();
        }, 5000);
    }
```

What I want to do is that when the user clicks on a `div` with `onclick="topbartoggle"` the `setInterval` function stops, and if he clicks again on it the `setInterval` function begins to work again:

```
function topbartoggle(){
    $('#top-bar').toggleClass('active');
    $('.top-bar-box').slideToggle();
    $('.top-bar-close').fadeToggle();   
}
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: The return value of `setInterval` is a timer ID that can be passed to `clearInterval` to stop the timer. Now, if you wanted to really *pause* the timer, i.e. have it maintain the delay it would have had if you hadn’t paused it after you resume it… that would be harder.

Comment: how would that be possible @minitech? that would be the greatest solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tickerID = false; 
function ticker(){ 
    tickerID = setInterval(function(){ 
         $('.slide').fadeToggle(); 
    }, 5000); 
}
```

To stop the ticker, use

> clearInterval(tickerID);

To start it again, just call ticker();

EDIT: Understanding that you need to toggle the ticker, add this to your toggling function:

```
if(tickerID != false) {
    clearInterval(tickerID);
    tickerID = false;
} else { ticker(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

setInterval returns a handle you can use to stop the interval, like this:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function() { // myInterval should be global
    something();
}, 5000);

function stopInterval()
{
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

So you can do like this:

```
<div onclick="stopInterval();anyOtherFunction();"></div> //anyOtherFunction could be any function you want.
```

Comment: But using this `onclick` I will lost the other actions I already have in the `topbartoggle` function.

Comment: @codek you can call one or more functions on onclick event by seperating them with ; as you can see in the edited version of above html two functions are called on onclick.

Comment: yeah it stops it, but how can I start it again after clicking on it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to maintain the same delay, it’s probably easiest to just keep the timer running:

```
var shouldTick = true;
var $slide = $('.slide');

setInterval(function () {
    if (shouldTick) {
        $slide.fadeToggle();
    }
}, 5000);

function topbartoggle() {
    shouldTick = !shouldTick;
    $('#top-bar').toggleClass('active');
    $('.top-bar-box').slideToggle();
    $('.top-bar-close').fadeToggle();   
}
```

Comment: Thanks minitech but now `$slide.fadeToggle` is not working at the load of  the page. It just stays there without fading to the other div automatically

Comment: @codek: Did you include the script after `.slide` in the page? If not, it needs to be in a `$(document).ready(…)`.

Comment: I'm wrapping it all in a `$(document).ready(…)` but when I click on the `div` with `onlick="topbartoggle"` I get: `topbartoggle is not defined`

Comment: @codek: Don’t use inline event handlers; just add it dynamically in external JavaScript with `$('#topbartoggle').on('click', topbartoggle);`. (Still, you could also move `function topbartoggle()` out of the `ready`.)