# How to stop js setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a function that change css background image every 1 second base on interval, and its all working fine, the problem is that now i want to stop the function that switches the background image and the interval setup keep overwriting me.

my code:

```
  var backgrounds = new Array(
'url(/srv/admin/img/announcement/envelope_blue.png)'
, 'url(/srv/admin/img/announcement/envelope_red.png)'

);

var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {   
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;
    jQuery("#open_msg_tlbr_img").css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
    jQuery("#open_msg_tlbr_img").css('width','35px');
    jQuery("#open_msg_tlbr_img").css('height','35px');


}
setInterval(nextBackground, 1000);

jQuery("#open_msg_tlbr_img").css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
```

I tried using :    clearInterval();

how do i stop this monster?

Comment: Please look up documentation on functions you're using, before asking questions like this on SO. The [`setInterval` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) have a link to the [function you need](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable to hold the return value of `setInterval` and then clear it:

```
var interval = setInterval(nextBackground, 1000);
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are **not** assigning object returned by `setInterval` so that you can clear it later, Pass the object returned by `setInterval` to clear in `clearInterval` function. Note you would need a global variable to be used in more then one functions.

Assigning object returned by `setInterval`

```
intr = setInterval(nextBackground, 1000);
```

Passing setInterval reference object to `clearInterval`

```
clearInterval(intr );
```

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval()` returns an interval ID, which you can pass to `clearInterval()`:

```
var nxtBckgrnd = setInterval(nextBackground, 1000);

/* later */
clearInterval(nxtBckgrnd );
```

[setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

[clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval)