# Call method form setInterval() causing exception

Tags: typescript, this

I would like to call function from setInterval(). Here is the idea:

```
class Greeter {
    element: HTMLElement;
    span: HTMLElement;
    timerToken: number;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        this.element = element;
        this.element.innerHTML += "The time is: ";
        this.span = document.createElement('span');
        this.element.appendChild(this.span);
        this.span.innerText = new Date().toUTCString();
        //this.element.style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg)";     
        //this.element.style.transition = "-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg)";         
    }

    start() {
        this.timerToken = setInterval(this.runningLoop(this.element), 500);        
    }

    stop() {
        clearTimeout(this.timerToken);
    }

    runningLoop(element: HTMLElement) {
        this.element.style.cssText = "-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg)";         
    }


}

window.onload = () => {
    var el = document.getElementById('content');
    var greeter = new Greeter(el);

    greeter.start();
};
```

In this case i getting an exception:

> Unhandled exception at line 13, column 9. Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid argument.

So i tried as following :

```
this.timerToken = setInterval(function () { this.runningLoop(this.element) }.bind, 500);
```

No exception but nothing happens..

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
setInterval(this.runningLoop(this.element), 500);
```

The above invokes `this.runningLoop` before passing it to `setInterval`, `setInterval` is expecting a function but is receiving `undefined`. Wrap the call in an arrow function...

```
setInterval(() => this.runningLoop(this.element), 500);
```

And since you're not using the element argument in `runningLoop`, you can remove the argument and pass the method to `setInterval`...

```
setInterval(this.runningLoop, 500);
```

Comment: how do you cancel it?

Comment: @crh225 assign setInterval to a variable. and then window.clearInterval(variableName);

Comment: setInterval stop solution  link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

This will be looping in the time that you want:
setInterval(() => function(), time in miliseconds);

Now, if you want to stop whenever! Write a var before the interval:
Declare on the top of your TS file:
varInterval: any;
this.varInterval = setInterval(() => function(), time in miliseconds);

You can call the method to stop like this:
clearInterval(this.varInterval);

This work for me!