# Regarding stopping page reload when button clicked

Tags: oracle-apex, popupwindow, page-refresh

I am working with Oracle Apex 4.2 where in i have a page which is Page1 and within the page i have a report region and a button. When i click on the button a Skill Builder Pop-up plugin hits up and a popup window opens up where in i created a form on another page which is Page2.

[image: Report Region with Button]

[image: Skill Builder Modal Popup]

I am adding a JavaScript page refresh for Page1 and it will automatically refreshes the page at particular intervals. Code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){cache_clear()},10000);
});
function cache_clear()
{
window.location.reload(true);
}
```

But when i click on the button, the page refresh on Page1 should stop and again it should get activated after closing the popup only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To stop process when button click use clearInterval() function.
Refer discussed thread [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)
for more details.