# JQUERY refresh div code needs time out

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code to refresh a certain div on my site for the chat;

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $('#chat_grab').load('chat_grab.php?randval=' + Math.random());
}, 5000);
```

However if someone leaves a page open, this will loop forever. Is there any way to change it so it times out if the base page hasnt been refreshed in say 10 minutes?

Comment: Can you post total code..

Comment: increment a global variable until it reaches 120 and then [clear it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

Comment: what do you understand by refresh the page, you could log mouse and keyboard events and if there is no event in a certain time the page is "dead"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = new Date();
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $('#chat_grab').load('chat_grab.php?randval=' + Math.random());
    if((new Date() - timer) > (10 * 60 * 1000)) {
        clearInterval(refreshId);
    }
}, 5000)
```