# Javascript value won't change

Tags: javascript, php, time

I have two files: the first is `script.js`; the second is `index.php` (but in this file `script.js` is included).

I have declared in `script.js` global variable `time = 12000`, but when if `sTime()` is called, the variable time should be changed to 2000. That variable i pass to another variable in index.php but it won't chages... What is the problem ?

**SCRIPT.js**

```
var time = 1200;

function STime() {
    time = 2000
}
```

**INDEX.php**

```
var tick = time; // to this variable i pass var from script.js (time)
var interval;
var l = 5;

function time_reset() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (l > 0) {
            post(4); // some ajax function
            l = l - 1;
        }
    }, tick); //interval time
}
```

One more thing is someone can tell me how i can stop this function **time_reset()**?

Comment: What value you are expecting from time? 1200 or 200?

Comment: to be changed to 2000 (i miss one 0) ...

Comment: You never actually call `STime()` and `si` is an undefined variable

Comment: he uses embedded js in that php script - i don't really understand why. Do you know, that JS is executed by the client while php is interpreted and executed from the server? the server just generates an HTML document via php and sends it to the client. I don't really understand the problem...please post more of your software architecture

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to tell you that, sTime() is called in script.js I didn't wanted to copy all code becaus is to large

Comment: To stop the setInterval() function call `clearInterval(interval)`, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript .

Comment: Man try to show whole code or we are blind here :(

Comment: @cars10 thank you so much! :D