# setInterval function doesn't stop even with clearInterval(timer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Hi so I have made a `setInterval` and as many before me I don't seem to be able to stop it.

I looked at the great internet and I found my solution - I thought - through `clearInterval` and a timer variable to make sure to stop the interval.

However I still don't seem to be able to stop my `setInterval`.

Anyhow, any help is appreciated and here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michaeltotkorsgaard/x0cLtbs3/1/)

Comment: first time you use `setInterval` it is not assigned to a variable. Need that variable to clear it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript

Comment: could you please provide minimum code that is not working? Without any additional mess?

Answer (score 2):

You did not assign your interval to a variable. If you do so you can then clear the interval by passing the variable to the clearInterval function:

Here is an example:

```
// start an interval
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){ ... }, 1000);

// stop an interval
clearInterval(myInterval);
```