# How to stop one function using another

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to coding so bear with me on this one.

I'm currently creating an Image gallery that has an AutoPlay button feature (this I've managed to create) however I can't seem to figure out a way to stop it without refreshing the page. Ideally I'd like to stop it using another separate function that calls on my first image when clicking it.

```
//Autoplay button//

function autoPlay() {
    (function () {
        var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery'); //Identifying image ID
        var delayInSeconds = 60; // setting number of seconds to delay images
        var images = ["Images/1.JPG", "Images/2.JPG", "Images/3.JPG", "Images/4.JPG", "Images/5.JPG", "Images/6.JPG", ]; // list of image names
        var num = 0;
        var changeImage = function () {
            var len = images.length;
            gallery.src = images[num++];
            if (num === len) {
                num = 0;
            }
        };
        setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 50);
    })();
}
document.getElementById("play").onclick = autoPlay;

//Stop button//

function stopButton() {
    document.getElementById('gallery').src = 'Images/1.JPG';
}
document.getElementById("stop").onclick = stopButton;
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML code ?

Comment: havn't read everything but I think `break; ` will do what you want

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: @Manu There's no loop here to break out of.

Comment: @juhana Yea, your right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't stop execution of one function from anywhere. But if you are using `setInterval()` then you can stop/clear it with [**clearInterval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval).

```
clearInterval(interval_ID);
```

Full code:

```
//Autoplay button//
var intervalVar;

function autoPlay() {
    (function () {
        var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery'); //Identifying image ID
        var delayInSeconds = 60; // setting number of seconds to delay images
        var images = ["Images/1.JPG", "Images/2.JPG", "Images/3.JPG", "Images/4.JPG", "Images/5.JPG", "Images/6.JPG", ]; // list of image names
        var num = 0;
        var changeImage = function () {
            var len = images.length;
            gallery.src = images[num++];
            if (num === len) {
                num = 0;
            }
        };
        intervalVar = setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 50);
    })();
}
document.getElementById("play").onclick = autoPlay;

//Stop button//

function stopButton() {
    clearInterval(intervalVar);
    document.getElementById('gallery').src = 'Images/1.JPG';
}
document.getElementById("stop").onclick = stopButton;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this did it for me. I had actually tried this method earlier, I just didn't name things properly.

Answer (score 4):

You can clear the interval, asigning first to a global variable:

```
// your code
window.varInterval = setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 50);
// your code

function stopButton (){
   clearInterval(varInterval); // this is the key
   document.getElementById('gallery').src = 'Images/1.JPG';
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: [Some w3c info about starting and stopping intervals](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I will delete my last answer. My shame. :(