# When is the page left/unloaded

Tags: html, forms, jsp, submit

I'm protocolling how long someone is staying at a certain jsp-page, so I have three functions called in my body-tag:

```
<body onunload="pageLeft();" onload="pageEnter(); startInterval();">
```

`pageEnter` sends an ajax-request to the server which contains the ID of the page and a '1' for page-enter.

`startInterval` starts an interval and sends every few seconds an ajax-request to the server which contains a '2' for being still there.

`pageLeft` send a '3' by ajax so I know the user has left the page.

Most essential are '1' and '3' which are used to group all the protocolled-data.

There is also a form on the page which has a submit-button:

```
<form action="/UpdateDB/Customers.jsp" method="POST" name="Custpost">
```

I was in the intention the form-data would be transferred to `Customers.jsp` afterwards the current page is unloaded and `Customers.jsp` loaded.
All my trials making the procedures in `Customers.jsp` work failed and now I found out why:

In the database are only 1s and 2s but no 3. This means the current page was never unloaded - yet the procedure has started already...

I thought about manually setting the 3-entry in the Customers.jsp but this would leave two such entries in the database. Also if the user just leaves the page no 3-entry would be left at all.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Try using the `onbeforeunload` method and let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately no changes at all...

Comment: Well, as I see now it actually got worse... now the pageLeft-Function is not called at all

Comment: Any particular browser? Or all or them?

Comment: No, I'm mostly focussing on Firefox. I think somewhere must be a chrome around, but I barely use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `onbeforeunload` didn't work as expected - after the replacement nothing was called. `onbeforesubmit` didn't look too promising either (but I haven't tried), but I got another idea:

First: Adding a Function which is called on submit to the form, also a variable to distinguish whether the function had been called or not. Also saving the ID of the interval in the variable `intervalid` (See: [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)):

```
var nosubmit = true;

        $(function () {
            $('#Custpostform').submit(function () {
                if (nosubmit) {
                    pageLeft();
                    clearInterval(intervalid);
                    nosubmit = false;
                    return true; // return false to cancel form action
                }
            });
        });

<!-- -->

<form action="/UpdateDB/Customers.jsp" method="POST" name="Custpost" name="Custpostform">
```

The rest remains pretty much the same, just the `onunload` is now slightly modiefied:

```
<body onunload="if (nosubmit) {
                pageLeft();
                nosubmit = false;
            }"
```

It's not really the solution I anticipated  but it works as supposed

Answer (score 0):

This way would seem to be better. I can get both `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` to work in Chrome and Firefox (I didn't test any others).

**See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgmann/e8xcbfjw/2/) for an interactive version.**

HTML:

```
<body onload="testLoad()" onunload="testUnload()" onbeforeunload="return testBeforeUnload()">

</body>
```

JS:

```
function testBeforeUnload() {
  return "test before unload event";
}
function testUnload() {
  console.log("test unload event");
}
```

Comment: Alright, it looks like a clean solution, but what's your definition of "better"?

Comment: My version looks cleaner which is what I think is better. This is what these events are designed for.