# JS and setInterval after an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval

I am showing a minutes/seconds counter for each question in a test (It doesn't always start from 0 because the user can return to a question).

The user navigates to the next question via ajax.

My problem is that after the first question JS also remembers the values from the previous questions.

The value that returns from the ajax call is ok.

```
<script>


$.ajax({
    type    : "POST",
    cache   : false,
    url     : "/ajax/Get_test_question",
    data: post_data,
    success: function(sec) {             
        show_timer(sec);        
    }
})


function pad(val) {
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
}   
function show_timer(sec) {  
        timer=setInterval(function () {
            console.log(sec)
            $("#seconds_counter").text(pad(++sec % 60));
            $("#minutes_counter").text(pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10)));

    }, 1000);
}

</script>
```

Comment: My problem is that after the first question JS also remembers the values from the previous questions. How is that a question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You should destroy the interval object as soon as you are displaying next question before before starting interval for next question.

```
var timer;
function show_timer(sec) { 
    if(timer) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    timer=setInterval(function () {
        console.log(sec)
        $("#seconds_counter").text(pad(++sec % 60));
        $("#minutes_counter").text(pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10)));

    }, 1000);
}
```