# How to stop a function that runs every 7 seconds if it finds any data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following runs every 7 second and calls the showAlert() function.
It looks if finds any data through the database. My question is how can I stop it if it finds any data?
So there is no need to run again and again.

```
setInterval(function myalert() {
$.getJSON("handler.php?type=alert&callback=?&cookie="+ y, showAlert);
}, 7000);
```

on backend this is a part of the php

```
$alertGroup = mysql_fetch_array($alertQuery);
$json[] = array($title,$text);
echo $callback . "(" . json_encode($json)  . ")";
```

this is the showAlert

```
function showAlert(data) {
console.log(data[0][0]);
console.log(data[0][1]);
}
```

Comment: `clearInterval`...

Comment: Use a named function and then clearInterval when data is found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to register your setInterval into a variable to take control of it's instance, look:

```
var my_interval = setInterval(function myalert() {
$.getJSON("handler.php?type=alert&callback=?&cookie="+ y, showAlert);
}, 7000);
```

To stop a running timer you should use clearInterval in the instance, look:

```
clearInterval(my_interval);
```

Comment: thank you, but where to place the clearInterval? Inside the showAlert ?