# Execute a function every 3 seconds in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Am trying to create a function in jquery mobile that autorefreshes itself every 3 seconds when on a certain page.

I have tried:

```
 $(document).on('pageshow', '#chat',function(){

function autoload(){
   console.log('its after 3 sec')
     } 
autoload();

 });
```

How can i change the function to console.log('its after 3 sec') after 3 seconds that is how can i add the time interval.The function should only execute when one is on the page(#chat)

Comment: `window.setInterval()` ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) method, it will execute the specified function at the desired interval (*in milliseconds*).

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#chat', function() {

    function autoload() {
        console.log('its after 3 sec')
    }

    setInterval(autoload(), 3000);

});
```

To stop execution when hiding the page, you could store the interval id and use the [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) method.

```
// store the interval id so we can clear it when the page is hidden
var intervalId;

$(document).on('pageshow', '#chat', function() {
    function autoload() {
        console.log('its after 3 sec')
    }
    intervalId = setInterval(autoload(), 3000);
});

$(document).on('pagehide', function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

You can also use the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) method, similar to the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) method.

```
// store the timeout id so we can clear it when the page is hidden
var timeoutId;

$(document).on('pageshow', '#chat', function() {
    function autoload() {
        console.log('its after 3 sec')
        timeoutId = setTimeout(autoload(), 3000);
    }
    autoload();
});

$(document).on('pagehide', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works but how can i stop the function on pagehide because the function continues even when am out of the page

Comment: Another practice is to use the interval ID. This will allow you to manage multiple intervals. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#chat',function(){
    function autoload(){
        console.log('its after 3 sec')
    } 
    window.setInterval(autoload, 3 * 1000)
});
```

Comment: It works what about stopping the function on pagehide

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI you will need to keep track of the timer with `var myInterval = window.setInterval(...)` and then you could permanently stop it with `window.onblur = function(){ clearInterval(myInterval) }`