# stop auto refresh when clicked on a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i would Like to stop auto refresh when i click on a specfic div this is how my code looks like at the moment

**jquery.js**

```
var documentInterval;
$(document).ready(function(){
  documentInterval setInterval(function(){
      $('#show_here').load('fetch_something.php')
  }, 3000);
});

$('#stop_auto_refresh').click(function(){
  clearInterval(documentInterval);
});
```

**index.php**

```
<div id="show_here"></div>
<div id="stop_auto_refresh" onclick="documentInterval()">Click To Stop Auto Refresh</div>
```

I would like to stop auto refresh when  click on the `id` `stop_auto_refresh`
is this possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: I thought the same, but... OP also asked how to set a click handler...?

Comment: no search research.you can find lot of answers,tutorials about adding click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Intervals are cleared as using the `clearInterval(intervalReference)`. You can add a click handler using the `.click()` jQuery api since you are using jQuery.

```
var documentInterval;

$(document).ready(function() {
   documentInterval = setInterval(function(){
      $('#show_here').load('fetch_something.php')
   }, 3000);

   $('#stop_auto_refresh').click(function(){
     clearInterval(documentInterval) 
   })

});
```

Comment: its not working do i need to call it in my button in the div `stop_auto_refresh`

Comment: i did add the '#' 
but it still isnt working any fixes

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thank you for your constructive, gentle handed approach on this, much appreciated. I've updated the post, and here is a [working plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/HlIKVO2elRsWBAaYnjkk?p=preview).

Comment: @Dan looks much better now

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your interval function as a var and then you can use an onclick event to fire another function that contains clearInterval(varObject);

Comment: Look at the example at [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval_clearinterval)