# clear all intervals from page when Focused in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to Stop Auto refresh when Focused in input box

```
<input type="text" id="input_box" />

   <script>
var  StopRefresh;

    $('#input_box').focus(function(){
      clearInterval('input_box');
    });

    </script>
```

this is what i have so far but it does not work 
can some how achieve this with jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stop auto refresh when clicked on a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106862/stop-auto-refresh-when-clicked-on-a-div)

Comment: show your auto refresh code also!!

Comment: clearing All Time out on pages

Comment: The only way to clear an existing interval is to call `clearInterval()` with the id of the one you want to clear. So if you want to clear *all* intervals you need to keep track of the interval ids - perhaps `.push()` them to an array each time you call `setInterval()`, and then in your `.click()` handler loop through the array to call `clearInterval()` for each.

Comment: Define a function which call `clearInterval()` function for all the intervals. That's the only way or you can [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635502/how-do-i-clear-all-intervals)

Comment: what if the id i want to click is in another page but no interval is set will i still be able to pull this off with just using `clearInterval('');`

Comment: I kinda changed my question can you guys have alook

Comment: Passing an empty string to `clearInterval()` doesn't do anything. As I already mentioned, you have to pass the id that was previously returned by `setInterval()`. Please read [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

Answer (score 0):

store your `setIntervel` to a `variable` like

```
var handle = setInterval('ANYTHING_YOUWANT', 20);
```

and when you want to clear it  use

```
clearInterval(handle);
```

if you want to clear on `textbox` focus so use

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#input_box').focus(function(){
          clearInterval('handle');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: so i should do this when  i need to call it 
`<input type="text" clearInterval(handle); /> `

Comment: @james2569 for that you have to write like this `<input type="text onfocus="clearInterval(handle) >"`