# Javascript, How to stop or pause the setInterval timer in this code?

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a code for a slideshow that runs automatically and all I want is to stop the timer when I click on the image and pause it when i hover over it.

I tried the `clearinterval` function but it didn't work at all, so I need your help please.

This is the JavaScript code:

```js
var m3D = function() {
    var e = 4;
    var t = [],
        n, r, i, s, o, 
  u = "",
        a = "",
        f = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            z: -650,
            s: 0,
            fov: 500
        },
        l = 0,
        c = 0;
    f.setTarget = function(e, t, n) {
        if (Math.abs(t - e) > .1) {
            f.s = 1;
            f.p = 0;
            f.d = t - e;
            if (n) {
                f.d *= 2;
                f.p = 9
            }
        }
    };
    f.tween = function(e) {
        if (f.s != 0) {
            f.p += f.s;
            f[e] += f.d * f.p * .01;
            if (f.p == 10) f.s = -1;
            else if (f.p == 0) f.s = 0
        }
        return f.s
    };
    var h = function(k, l, c, h, p) {
        if (l) {
            this.url = l.url;
            this.title = l.title;
            this.color = l.color;
            this.isLoaded = false;
            if (document.createElement("canvas").getContext) {
                this.srcImg = new Image;
                this.srcImg.src = u + l.src;
                this.img = document.createElement("canvas");
                this.canvas = true;
                r.appendChild(this.img)
            } else {
                this.img = document.createElement("img");
                this.img.src = u + l.src;
                r.appendChild(this.img)
            }
   
            function v(e, t) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (t - e + 1)) + e
            }
            function m() {
                var e = t.length;
                var n = v(0, t.length);
                l.src = u + "photo" + n + ".jpg";
                if (f.s) return;
                try {
                    if (t[n].canvas == true) {
                        f.tz = t[n].z - f.fov;
                        f.tx = t[n].x;
                        f.ty = t[n].y;
                        if (s) {
                            s.but.className = "button viewed";
                            s.img.className = "";
                            s.img.style.cursor = "pointer";
                            s.urlActive = false;
                            o.style.visibility = "hidden"
                        }
                        t[n].img.className = "button selected";
                        d(false);
                        s = t[n]
                    } else {}
                } catch (r) {}
            }
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
// this is the Interval timer 
var g = setInterval(m, 6e3);
            this.img.onclick = function() 
   {
/*
i want to reset the timer OR increase it when i click here
*/
alert("click");








                if (f.s) return;
                if (this.diapo.isLoaded) {
                    if (this.diapo.urlActive) {
                        top.location.href = this.diapo.url
                    } else {
                        f.tz = this.diapo.z - f.fov;
                        f.tx = this.diapo.x;
                        f.ty = this.diapo.y;
                        if (s) {
                            s.but.className = "button viewed";
                            s.img.className = "";
                            s.img.style.cursor = "pointer";
                            s.urlActive = false;
                            o.style.visibility = "hidden"
                        }
                        this.diapo.but.className = "button selected";
                        d(false);
                        s = this.diapo
                    }
                }
            };
   
            this.but = document.createElement("div");
            this.Img = document.createElement("Img");
            this.but.className = "button";
            this.Img.src = a + l.src;
            this.but.appendChild(this.Img);
            i.appendChild(this.but);
            this.but.diapo = this;
            this.Img.style.left = Math.round(this.but.offsetWidth * 1.2 * (k % e)) + "px";
            this.Img.style.top = Math.round(this.but.offsetHeight * 1.2 * Math.floor(k / e)) + "px";
            this.Img.style.zIndex = "50";
   
            this.but.onclick = this.img.onclick;
            n = this.img;
            this.img.diapo = this;
            this.zi = 25e3
        } else {
            this.img = document.createElement("div");
            this.isLoaded = true;
            this.img.className = "fog";
            r.appendChild(this.img);
            this.w = 300;
            this.h = 300;
            this.zi = 15e3
        }
        this.x = c;
        this.y = h;
        this.z = p;
        this.css = this.img.style
    };
    h.prototype.anim = function() {
        if (this.isLoaded) {
            var e = this.x - f.x;
            var t = this.y - f.y;
            var n = this.z - f.z;
            if (n < 20) n += 5e3;
            var r = f.fov / n;
            var i = this.w * r;
            var s = this.h * r;
            this.css.left = Math.round(l + e * r - i * .5) + "px";
            this.css.top = Math.round(c + t * r - s * .5) + "px";
            this.css.width = Math.round(i) + "px";
            this.css.height = Math.round(s) + "px";
            this.css.zIndex = this.zi - Math.round(n)
        } else {
            this.isLoaded = this.loading()
        }
    };
    h.prototype.loading = function() {
        if (this.canvas && this.srcImg.complete || this.img.complete) {
            if (this.canvas) {
                this.w = this.srcImg.width;
                this.h = this.srcImg.height;
                this.img.width = this.w;
                this.img.height = this.h;
                var e = this.img.getContext("2d");
                e.drawImage(this.srcImg, 0, 0, this.w, this.h)
            } else {
                this.w = this.img.width;
                this.h = this.img.height
            }
            this.but.className += " loaded";
            return true
        }
        return false
    };
    var p = function() {
        l = r.offsetWidth * .5;
        c = r.offsetHeight * .5
    };
    var d = function(e) {
        var n = 0,
            r;
        while (r = t[n++]) {
            if (r.but) {
                r.css.msInterpolationMode = e ? "bicubic" : "nearest-neighbor";
                r.css.imageRendering = e ? "optimizeQuality" : "optimizeSpeed"
            }
        }
    };
    var v = function(e) {
        r = document.getElementById("screen");
        i = document.getElementById("bar");
        o = document.getElementById("urlInfo");
        p();
        var n = 0,
            s, u = e.length;
        while (s = e[n++]) {
            var a = 1e3 * (n % 4 - 1.5);
            var f = Math.round(Math.random() * 4e3) - 2e3;
            var l = n * (5e3 / u);
            t.push(new h(n - 1, s, a, f, l));
            var c = t.length - 1;
            for (var d = 0; d < 3; d++) {
                var a = Math.round(Math.random() * 4e3) - 2e3;
                var f = Math.round(Math.random() * 4e3) - 2e3;
                t.push(new h(c, null, a, f, l + 100))
            }
   /*
            var d = t.length - 1;
            for (var v = 0; v < 3; v++) {
                var a = Math.round(Math.random() * 4e3) - 2e3;
                var f = Math.round(Math.random() * 4e3) - 2e3;
                t.push(new h(d, null, a, f, l + 100))
            }
    */
        }
        m()
    };
    var m = function() {
        if (f.tx) {
            if (!f.s) f.setTarget(f.x, f.tx);
            var e = f.tween("x");
            if (!e) f.tx = 0
        } else if (f.ty) {
            if (!f.s) f.setTarget(f.y, f.ty);
            var e = f.tween("y");
            if (!e) f.ty = 0
        } else if (f.tz) {
            if (!f.s) f.setTarget(f.z, f.tz);
            var e = f.tween("z");
            if (!e) {
                f.tz = 0;
                d(true);
                if (s.url) {
                    s.img.style.cursor = "pointer";
                    s.urlActive = true;
                    s.img.className = "href";
                    o.diapo = s;
                    o.onclick = s.img.onclick;
                    o.innerHTML = s.title || s.url;
                    o.style.visibility = "visible";
                    o.style.color = s.color || "#fff";
                    o.style.top = Math.round(s.img.offsetTop + s.img.offsetHeight - o.offsetHeight - 5) + "px";
                    o.style.left = Math.round(s.img.offsetLeft + s.img.offsetWidth - o.offsetWidth - 5) + "px"
                } else {
                    s.img.style.cursor = "default"
    }
    
    
    
    
    
/*
i want to pause the timer when i hover here
*/
s.img.onmouseover = function(){
 alert("mouseover");
};







            }
        }
        var n = 0,
            r;
        while (r = t[n++]) r.anim();
        var g = setTimeout(m, 32)
    };
    return {
        init: v
    }
}()
```

And as you see, on line 90 I have the `setInterval` timer function and after it the `onclick` function where I need to "reset" the timer, and on line 270 the `onmouseover` function where I need to "pause" the timer.

So how to do this?

Comment: is it really a minimal example ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve more than 270 lines for a clearInterval is a bit excecive

Comment: How did `clearInterval` not work? Show us the code and what didn't work about it. You have to call it with the value `setInterval` previously returned, e.g. `var myTimer = setInterval(...);` and later `clearInterval(myTimer);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: You could also try adding a flag variable in the function the timer calls which prevents it from changing the image. For example, you could say `function changeImage(){if(!pauseSlideshow){/*do the change thing*/};}` and then start it as you would, but when you hover over the image or click pause, you set `pauseSlideshow` to `true` and the image won't be changed until you set it to `false` (or another falsy value).

Comment: @AxelH - that is not my code i cant minimal it, sorry for that.

Comment: @al-dr Who's code it is ? But recreate an example to remove everything not important... Basicly you need to save the instance receive by setInterval to keep the variable in the correct scope and call clearInterval with this variable.

Comment: @CherryDT - `i tried clearInterval(g);` and i tried to put it every where and no thing happened

Comment: g is in the wrong scope so it doesn't exist everywhere.

Comment: @jdgregson - i am a newbie how to add aflag variable or doing that?

Comment: @AxelH - i found that script in my pc in a file called slideshowPack5.rar

Comment: @AxelH - why g is wrong? the `var g = setInterval`

Comment: It's inside the scope of the function `h` so it can be used on in there. Properly indenting the code (for example by stuffing it into a [online beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)) would make this clearer. If you want to continue hacking around with the code and trying your luck, you could additionally assign it to a global variable, e.g. `var g = window.slideShowTimer = setInterval(...)`, then you could access `window.slideShowTimer` from anywhere. But it's not good practice like this. EDIT: Actually it may be that you *can* access `g` from the point you tried to, but the code is confusing!

Comment: You found it in your pc, ok... First. Outside of the function h, you can't use the var g since you exit the scope where the var was created. declare g outside of the function m3d (just `var g;`) and remove the **var** when you set the interval (to use the correct var scope)

Comment: Your JavaScript says `function m() {` in one place and then `var m = function() {` later on. Are you sure you meant to override the first `m()` function?

Comment: @ jdgregson - realy i do not know. so sorry for that.

Comment: @jdgregson this is in a different scope. This script as been obfuscate but is correct.

Comment: @AxelH Oh I see. The one that could benefit from my flag variable idea must be the first, `function m() {`, as it has the `l.src = u + "photo" + n + ".jpg";` JPEG changing bit.

Comment: I have an edit waiting for a review where I cleared the code to highlight the code to update. That could help.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a flag variable. Add `var pauseSlideshow = false;` somewhere at the top of the file, so it will be in the global scope. Change the `m()`function like so:

```
var m = function() {
    if(!pauseSlideshow) {
        /*
         *
         * all of the code already in m()
         *
         */
    } // make sure to add this additional curly brace
}
```

And then you need an `onmouseover` and an `onmouseout` function to toggle `pauseSlideshow`, like this:

```
s.img.onmouseover = function() {
    pauseSlideshow = true;
};

s.img.onmouseout = function() {
    pauseSlideshow = false;
};
```

Comment: thank you ver very very much @jdgregson - i am trying your solution now hope it works

Comment: @al-dr make sure you try it with the correct `m()` in the correct scope, as it appears there are two of them. You probably want `function m() {`