# jQuery setInterval Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running a function that checks a remote script every second and updates a progress bar. I'm new with `setInterval` and am having an issue with getting it to stop looping after it's done.

I've added `var interval` post function, and `clearInterval(interval);` in several different places - basically like covering my eyes and pinning the tail on the donkey - and have had no success. Where would I set `clearInterval` to stop the loop once `data` has reached 100?

```
function getProgress(hash) {
  setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://domain.com/script.php?hash=' + hash,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data < 100) {
            getProgress();
          } else {
            $('#progress-bar').hide();
          }
        },
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Please see the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript

Comment: Please post how you use `var interval` and `clearInterval`

Comment: Since you're using `setInterval` your function will be called, no need to call it manually with `getProgress()`

Comment: Why do you pass `hash` as a parameter at initial call to `getProgress`, but not within `success` callback? `hash` would be `undefined` at second through n calls to `getProgress`? What is expected result if response takes longer than one second to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer assuming that you are unable to stop the previous intervals. You're calling `getProgress` method everytime the `data < 100`. Which calls to another `setInterval` method, and re-create a new `id` for that interval.

Let's say that `getProgress` method called in a loop for more than one time, if you do,

```
var intervalId;
function getProgress(hash) {
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {..}, 1000);
}
```

And the next time you want to stop the interval, you'd call `clearInterval(intervalId)`. And this is very **wrong**. You have more than **one** interval, and you just happened to stop the last one while the previous ones are still running until `data < 100` is **false**.

I'd suggest to store your interval ids in an array, like..

```
var intervalIds = [];
function getProgress(hash) {
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {..}, 1000);
  intervalIds.push(intervalId);
}
```

And if the next time you want to stop interval, you can do it like..

```
for (var idx in intervalIds) {
   clearInterval(intervalIds[idx]);
}
```

But, that's just one way to stop all the intervals. What I am trying to say here is **your code is ugly**. If the reason you're using `setInterval` method is to wait for `1000 ms` to retrieve another data, `setTimeout` would do the job just fine. And here's a sample to use it and passing the parameter back.

```
function getProgress(hash){
   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://domain.com/script.php?hash=' + hash,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data < 100) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              getProgress(hash);
            }, 1000);
          } else {
            $('#progress-bar').hide();
          }
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for the explanation. I tried `setTimeout` with my previous code and couldn't get it to work so I changed it to `setInterval`. Whoops! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your code is done when the progress bar is hidden. You need to set you Interval to some variable which you can use to clear it.

```
function getProgress(hash) {
  var someVariable = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://domain.com/script.php?hash=' + hash,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data < 100) {
            getProgress();
          } else {
            $('#progress-bar').hide();
            clearInterval(someVariable);
          }
        },
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good example : 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_clearinterval

```
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
  myTimer()
}, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

when you call setInterval you need to set the return value to variable.
then you can call clearInterval with this parameter and it will stop.