# How to start and stop checking a condition every few minutes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am developing a javascript application where I have to do this.

1. Check every 5 seconds that whether the page contains an element with  tag.
2. Once, the  tag is detected, then start my video tracking function.
3. DO NOT check again every 5 seconds that whether the page contains an element with  tag - once a  tag has been detected and my video tracking function has been started.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
       setInterval(function() { 
        var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

        console.log(myVideo);
        if (myVideo !=  null)
          {
      myVideo.id = 'video-stream';
  var colors = new tracking.ColorTracker(['magenta', 'cyan', 'yellow']);

  colors.on('track', function(event) {
    if (event.data.length === 0) {
      // No colors were detected in this frame.
    } else {
      event.data.forEach(function(rect) {
        console.log(rect.x, rect.y, rect.height, rect.width, rect.color);
      });
    }
  });

  tracking.track("#video-stream", colors);
          }
         }, 5000);
  </script>
```

Right now, it just keeps checking even if a  tag is detected, So how do I stop it from checking once it  `if (myVideo !=  null)` condition is fulfilled and it has gotten into it?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setInterval` function returns a value with you can then use to stop the interval in conjunction with `clearInterval`, so in your case:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
    ...
    if (myVideo !==  null) {
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
    ...
}, 5000);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thats perfect! Thanks @m-a-r-c-e-l-i-n-o

Answer (score 1):

Create a function, which calls itself after 5s if the tag doesn't exist:

```
function testVideo() {
  var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

  console.log(myVideo);
  if (myVideo != null) {
    myVideo.id = 'video-stream';
    var colors = new tracking.ColorTracker(['magenta', 'cyan', 'yellow']);

    colors.on('track', function(event) {
      if (event.data.length === 0) {
        // No colors were detected in this frame.
      } else {
        event.data.forEach(function(rect) {
          console.log(rect.x, rect.y, rect.height, rect.width, rect.color);
        });
      }
    });

    tracking.track("#video-stream", colors);
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(test, 5000); //try again in 5s
  }
} //testVideo

testVideo(); //call the function
```

Comment: Thankyou! @Rick but I think m-a-r-c-e-l-i-n-o's answers is more easy and straight forward

Answer (score 1):

You should define your interval in variable and when you detect the video you should use `clearInterval()`

https://jsfiddle.net/o127oqjr/

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function() { 
  var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

  console.log(myVideo);
  if (myVideo !=  null)
  {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myVideo.id = 'video-stream';
    var colors = new tracking.ColorTracker(['magenta', 'cyan', 'yellow']);

    colors.on('track', function(event) {
      if (event.data.length === 0) {
        // No colors were detected in this frame.
      } else {
        event.data.forEach(function(rect) {
          console.log(rect.x, rect.y, rect.height, rect.width, rect.color);
        });
      }
    });

    tracking.track("#video-stream", colors);
  }
    else{
    console.log('notFound')
  }

}, 5000);
```