# Clear 'looped' timeout closed in function - how to return id of interval that I would have ability to clear it

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout, setinterval, cleartimeout

I have two functions inside my Class. First fires timeout and looped it (works like interval) and second to clearTimeout. My problem is, that clearTimeout doesn't work. How can I fix it?

```
this.startMove = function() {
    setTimeout(function handler() {
        self.moveMonster(moveMonsterCallback);
        setTimeout(handler, self.speed);
    }, this.speed);
};

this.stopMove = function() {
    clearTimeout(self.startMove());
}
```

For example I want to run these functions on click.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: better use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame for animating something in your page. Also be aware of the fact, that the delay of setTimeout is not guaranteed! It can differ

Comment: well you are creating a new interval when you call startMove in stopMove....

Comment: PRMoureu, its simple clear interval. I have more complicated problem and your suggest doesn't work for me

JoshuaK, thanks I will check it, but now i I have to resolve problem by way i wrote above

epascarello you are right. I desperately have trying all possible combinations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this works for you :

```
this.startMove = function() {
    self.timeout = setTimeout(function handler() {
        self.moveMonster(moveMonsterCallback);
        self.startMove();
    }, self.speed);
};

this.stopMove = function() {
    clearTimeout(self.timeout);
}
```

So basically I have reused the @Michael Horn's solution. And, I am happy to use this answer as an to his edited answer (if the question resolves).

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. I don't know, why I have using handler() and complicated function, if it's so easy. Probably I have mixed different solutions found in the Internet. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your timeout to a handler:

```
this.startMove = function() {
    self.timeout = setTimeout(function handler() {
        self.moveMonster(moveMonsterCallback);
        setTimeout(handler, self.speed);
    }, this.speed);
};

this.stopMove = function() {
    clearTimeout(self.timeout);
}
```

---

## Edit

As michalgrzasko mentions, **the above code doesn't work**. The reason being that the handle is assigned to the wrong timeout function. The outer timeout is only set once, while the inner timeout is called in a recursive loop, thus that is the timeout which needs to be cleared.

```
this.startMove = function() {
    setTimeout(function handler() {
        self.moveMonster(moveMonsterCallback);
        self.handle = setTimeout(handler, self.speed);
    }, this.speed);
};

this.stopMove = function() {
    clearTimeout(self.timeout);
}
```

### However

Again, as michalgrzasko and several others point out, the better solution is to use setInterval, as it is easier to read, and thus safer:

```
this.startMove = function() {
    self.moveInterval = setInterval(function handler() {
        self.moveMonster(moveMonsterCallback);
    }, this.speed);
};

this.stopMove = function() {
    clearInterval(self.moveInterval);
}
```

Comment: He's creating a new timeout-Handler, not an interval-handler. I'm not sure if it's fail safe, if `this.speed` is very small.

Comment: @JoshuaK It's safe. Either `stopMove()` runs before the timeout occurs, and it clears it. Or it runs after, and clearing it has no effect. JS is single-threaded so there's no concurrency problem.

Comment: @Barmar yeah. but self.timeout holds only the first created handle and is never overridden by the setTimeout call **inside** the handler function. He calls handler and not this.startMove after the first call. It wont work if I see it clear

Comment: first why would you need to call setTimeout inside setTimeout ? Just call the this.startMove() again. ...; which in this case would self.startMove().

Comment: @82Tuskers in this case you're right. But it makes sense if you want to do more stuff when the animation starts, but not in every step (showing a message "Animation started" or something like this).

Comment: in this case the question is: why using setTimeout instead of setInterval? If `moveMonster` needs less time than self.speed it's the easier solution

Comment: This solustion doesn't work for me. On execute stopMove(), interval still is running.  
Guys, honestly I don't know why I am using timeout instead interval. I read that timeout is safer, isn't it?

Comment: Ah, after taking a better look I see I assigned the wrong timeout to the handle. It should have been assigned to the timeout inside of handler(), since that's the one which gets recursively called. Having said that, yes I think it would be both simpler and safer to use an interval

Answer (score 0):

If you use setTimeout or setInterval and want the ability to cancel them, you need to save the returnvalue of this function in a variable. The return-value is a handler, that can be used in clearTimeout or clearInterval.

In this scenario setInterval would be easier if the moveMonster function has a smaller time consumption than this.speed.

```
this.startMove = function() {
    this.startMove.intervalHandler = setInterval(function handler() {
        self.moveMonster(moveMonsterCallback);
    }, this.speed);
};

this.stopMove = function() { clearInterval(this.startMove.intervalHandler); }
```

**I prefer using the function scope to save such things like Handler. If you don't like it use the parent scope or the context**

If it's important to use setTimeout instead of setInterval you have solution in other answers. It's simply the same: Save the returnvalue of setTimeout und use it later with clearTimeout.

---

If moveMonsterCallback should be called if the animation is over, take a look at promises instead of callbacks. With callbacks you're getting fast in a position, it's hard to track the callings.

---

A word on animations: They're tricky! Don't use setTimeout. Better call requestAnimationFrame on the window object.

```
function step(timestamp) {
  if (!step.startTime) step.startTime = timestamp;
  var delta = step.getDelta(timestamp);
  // do the calculations of how far you have to move the monster in this time range
  // move the monster...
  ...
  // animation is stopped? If not: We want to animate another timeframe
  if (!step.stopped) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}
step.startTime = null;
step.stopped = false;
step.getDelta = (timestamp)=>timestamp-step.startTime;

function stopMove() {
  step.stopped = true;
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

This solution provides a better result, because it's independent of the precision of setTimeout. It works with time differences

Comment: Hi, thanks for such extensive response! My moveMonster function changes the property of monster instance (eg. monster.x += 1 / monster.y += -1, etc.) depends to monster.direction (right, left, up, down). I want every 500ms change the values of x and y and execute callback function which changes css in DOM element. So... moveMonster isn't anything what i could animate. I don't know how to combine requestAnimationFrame with my solution. I am pasting here my code only to look at my functions to better understanding my Class: https://jsfiddle.net/pesxgacu/ (obviously here it dosen't work)