# Chrome extension polling html lags page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a script (extension) that selects an HTML tag and does some stuff to it. However, this HTML tag will dynamically load up on the page at some given time, and I want to detect it as soon as it loads. Currently I am polling the html page in a while loop (checking for undefined) but it is lagging the page a lot. Is there a workaround?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // some code
  var sizesList=document.getElementsByClassName("exp-pdp-size-dropdown-container nsg-form--drop-down--option-container selectBox-options nsg-form--drop-down exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown two-column-dropdown selectBox-dropdown-menu")[0];
  while(typeof(sizesList) == 'undefined') {
    setTimeout(function() {}, 700)
    sizesList=document.getElementsByClassName("exp-pdp-size-dropdown-container nsg-form--drop-down--option-container selectBox-options nsg-form--drop-down exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown two-column-dropdown selectBox-dropdown-menu")[0];
  }
// some more code
}
```

I'm testing it on [this](https://store.nike.com/ca/en_gb/pd/air-max-1-sc-shoe/pid-12027690/pgid-11808104) webpage.

Comment: That while loop probably completely locks up. It might be nicer to have a function that calls setTimeout on itself until that element appears.

Answer (score 0):

The page is lagging because you're executing `sizesList=document.getElementsByClassName(...` *continuously*. The setTimeout is asynchronous, so it won't do anything.

To poll every 700ms like you expect, you should consider `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if(typeof(sizesList) == 'undefined')
    sizesList=document.getElementsBy(...
}, 700)
```

Comment: Thanks! So if my variable becomes defined, how would I exit the interval and carry on with the rest of the code?

Comment: Yeah! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript