# setInterval call to function with other arg

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a function called "showCustomer" that get number between 1-5 and return something.

I want to use setInterval, to run this function every 5 second but with another number.

Its not working, i don't understand why its not working to me. here is the code.

```
setInterval(function () {
    var i = 1;
    showCustomer(i);
    i++;
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just move the declaration of variable `i` before the `setInterval()` call:

```
var i = 1;

setInterval(function () {
    showCustomer(i);
    i++;
}, 5000);
```

The anonymous function you've set as a callback for `setInterval` gets called every 5 seconds in your code. In every call, you're setting `i` to 1 which resets it every time.

Moving `i` outside the `setInterval` callback makes it persist the the current value.

Comment: thank you, but how i can stop when i equal to 5 and start again?

Comment: @Maxim -- please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript). It is always a good practice to search beforehand.

Comment: i saw this post but dont understand.

Comment: @Maxim -- but it is quite straight-forward. You assign the return value of `setInterval` in a variable, say `x`. In the callback, check if `i === 5` then call `clearinterval` with `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use `var`, you redeclare the value of that variable. So you only should declare the counter one time.

Every time that the browser calls the callback `showCustomer` the `if statement` evaluates if the browser should make a new call.

`clearInvertal()` it's the method to stop the `setInterval()` method.

```js
var id = 1;

var show5times = window.setInterval(showCustomer, 5000);

function showCustomer() {

  alert(id);
  
  id++;
  
  if(id > 5) {
  
   window.clearInterval(show5times);
  
  }

}
```