# Two variable are equal stop request using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

If the two variables are equal `6s ==6s`, `Secdata` Images need to load ELSE loading GIF I should show

I'm using MongoDB. My array object

```
"sec": "6s"
"Secdata" : ["1.jpg", "2.jpg"];
```

I have four buttons in HTML element

```
<a href="" data-sec="4s">4s</a>
<a href="" data-sec="6s">6s</a>
<a href="" data-sec="8s">8s</a>
<a href="" data-sec="10s">10s</a>
```

When I click `6s` button. It will take 6s data value and compare with a collection data `sec`.

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
         function checkAjax(id, tmax, tid, pid) {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '../tmax',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: {
                     id: id,
                     tmax: tmax,
                     tid: tid,
                     pid: pid
                 },
                 success: function(response) {
                     $("#sliderA").hide();
                     $("#sliderB").hide();
                     $("#sliderC").hide();
                     $("#tmaxsecsdata").html(response);
                     if (second == tmax) {

                         checkAjax(id, tmax, tid, pid);

                     } else {
                         var loadinggif = "<img src='loader.gif' class='img-responsive'>";
                         $("#tmaxsecsdata").html(loadinggif);
                     }
                 },
                 error: function() {
                     console.log("Error");
                 }
             })
         }

         $(".secs li a").on("click", function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var id = $(this).data("jsonid");
             var tmax = $(this).data("secs");
             var tid = $(this).data("tid");
             var pid = $(this).data("pid");

             checkAjax(id, tmax, tid, pid);
         })

     })
```

The **second** variable, I'm getting from the backend

**My problem**

When clicking my button, I'm getting a variable (`6s` => it will be anything 4s,8s,10s,4s). Same like that, I'm getting another variable in my collection. Now I have two variable, This two variables I use to compare ('6s' => it will be anything 4s,8s,10s,4s). If the two variables or not equal, The loader will show on my page. An hour after in my collection will get an update and I will get equal variable. Now I need sho the images.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: is `tmaxSec` part of the response ? and is the response JSON ?

Comment: That is array object in my collection. If my the ' tmaxSec[]' Object is not empty, i should stop the calling

Comment: You probably want to defer the NEXT call 3000 ms after the last one completes just in case you have latency issues and thus not pile up unfinished requests.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `setInterval`, just call a new ajax from the `success` callback if the array is empty.

So assuming that `tmaxSec` is part of the `response` then

```js
function checkAjax(id, tmax, tid, pid){
  $.ajax({
        url:'../tmax',
        type:'POST',
        data:{id:id,tmax:tmax,tid:tid,pid,pid},
        success: function(response){
            $("#sliderA").hide();
            $("#sliderB").hide();
            $("#sliderC").hide();
            $("#tmaxsecsdata").html(response);

            if (response.tmaxSec.length === 0) {
                   checkAjax(id,tmax,tid,pid);
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("Error");
        }
    })
}

$(".secs li a").on("click",function(e){

      var id = $(this).data("jsonid");
      var tmax = $(this).data("secs");
      var tid = $(this).data("tid");
      var pid = $(this).data("pid");

      checkAjax(id,tmax,tid,pid);
})
```

Comment: Without refresh updated data not showing. If i reload the browser then showing

Comment: @AshokCharu there must be something else at play. Are you clicking on multiple `.secs li a` links ?

Comment: @AshokCharu but the code will clear the `$("#tmaxsecsdata")` when any ajax returns `[]` for the `tmaxSec`. So if you click two links one after the other the first might return data but the second might not and it will clear the `#tmaxsecsdata` element

Comment: If the value equal also it's checking multiple time. How to stop checking       checkAjax(id,tmax,tid,pid);

Comment: @AshokCharu your original question said to stop checking only if the array object is empty. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974/128165 for how to compare arrays as it is not trivial

Comment: @AshokCharu **do not change the question with a new one**. Create a new question with your new problem and revert this to its previous state.

Comment: but I already created, hereafter I won't create like this, help me with this problem