# I want to stop this function after it clicks 100 Times

Tags: javascript

I just want to stop this code after it clicks 100 times. I'm a beginning coder. I'm using the second script to work.

```
<form method="post" action="cashads.php" target="clk">
  <input type="hidden" name="ad_new" value="145">
  <input type="submit" id="clk" class="buttonN" style="background- 
    color:#1D03FB" value="Open Ad">
```

```
setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("clk").click();},42000);
```

This is second Script for stoping click after 100 times.

```
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("clk").remove();},4200000);
```

Comment: How about maintaining a counter for that ?

Comment: Instead of `document.getElementById("clk").remove()` try removing the interval itself. Try `var interval = setInterval(...)` and then `window.clearInterval(interval)`

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) is always helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable `i` that you can increment each time you call the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) callback function. Once you reach your limit, just use the [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) function to prevent any further click.

```js
var currentClick = 1;
// Change those values below according to your needs
var maxClick = 3; // Number of clicks
var delayClick = 1000; // Delay in milliseconds

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  console.log(currentClick);
  if (currentClick++ === maxClick) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, delayClick);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explained

To make this clean and easy to read, you can see that in this solution, there's a simple counter variable, increment that for every time the button has been clicked, once the counter has reached 99 then make the `onclick` property set to `null`.

In this example, I've just made it so that it will also clear the interval variable, aka make use of `clearInterval`.

```js
// Get access to the button.
const btn = document.getElementById("clk");
let counter = 0,
  interval;

// Once the button has been clicked 100 times. 
const onComplete = () => {
  btn.onclick = null;
  clearInterval(interval);
};

// Handle the click event. 
// Prints 0 - 99 (aka 100 clicks)
const clickHandler = () => {
  console.log(counter);
  counter++;
};

// Handle the on click event.
btn.onclick = () => counter >= 100 ? onComplete() : clickHandler();

// Demo 
interval = setInterval(() => {
  btn.click();
}, 0);
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="clk" class="buttonN" style="background-color:#1D03FB" value="Open Ad">
```