# Pause autonomous function if user interacts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a carousel that runs automatically, but if a user interacts with the controls I want the carousel to reset its timer. 
What ive built works to an extent, but if you interact with the `control-dot` the timer isnt reset so it throws some funny results...

Here's my JS

```js
/* Js for carousel */
$('.steps__step-1').addClass('active');
$(function() {
  var lis = $('.step'),
    currentHighlight = 0;
  N = 5; // Duration in seconds
  setInterval(function() {
    currentHighlight = (currentHighlight + 1) % lis.length;
    lis.removeClass('active').eq(currentHighlight).addClass('active');
  }, N * 1000);
});

$('.control-dot').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  var itemNo = $(this).index() - 1;
  $('.step').eq(itemNo).addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tnzLha3o/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: did you flag your own question as a duplicate? that's not common..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store interval id in a variable (`let intervalId = setInterval(...)`) and then use it to restart it.

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gudzdanil/uzoydp6a/2/

So that your code will look like:

```
var duration = 5;
var lis = $('.step'),
    currentHighlight = 0;
var intervalId = null;
$(function() {
  $('.steps__step-1').addClass('active');
  runCarousel();
});

$('.control-dot').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  var itemNo = $(this).index() - 1;
  $('.step').eq(itemNo).addClass('active');
  rerunCarousel();
});

function rerunCarousel() {
  if(intervalId) clearInterval(intervalId);
  intervalId = null;
  runCarousel();
}

function runCarousel() {
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    currentHighlight = (currentHighlight + 1) % lis.length;
    lis.removeClass('active').eq(currentHighlight).addClass('active');
  }, N * 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to stop it.

```
 var stop = false
    $('.steps__step-1').addClass('active');
    $(function() {
        var lis = $('.step'),
            currentHighlight = 0;
            N = 5; // Duration in seconds
        setInterval(function() {
            if (!stop) {
            currentHighlight = (currentHighlight + 1) % lis.length;
            lis.removeClass('active').eq(currentHighlight).addClass('active');
            }
        }, N * 1000);

    });

    $('.control-dot').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        var itemNo = $(this).index() - 1;
        $('.step').eq(itemNo).addClass('active');
        stop = !stop
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/quvgxz63/