# Can't stop interval inside async loop - Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I created a interval that executing each second. Inside that interval i have a for loop that submitting a request to a server throw an Observable.
I want to stop the interval when a condition turns to true.
Although the condition is true the interval keep going.

```
private setStatusChecker() {
    const taskInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.uploadedFiles.forEach((task, index) => {
        if (this.uploadedFiles.length === this.completedTasksNumber || this.stopGetUploadStatusInterval === true) {
          clearInterval(taskInterval);
          this.uploadingProcessActive = false;
          this.stopGetUploadStatusInterval = true;
        }
        if (task.state !== 'SUCCESS') {
          this.getUploadStatus(task.id).subscribe((response: any) => {
            if (response.info === null) {
              return;
            }
            const fileStatus: UploadStatus = {
              id: task.id,
              state: response.state,
            };
            this.uploadedFiles[index] = fileStatus;
          });
        }
        if (task.state === 'SUCCESS') {
          this.completedTasksNumber++;
          task.state = 'COMPLETED';
        }
      });
      this.uploadedFilesCurrentStatus.next(this.uploadedFiles);
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: have you actually checked it calls the clearInterval ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: @jonathan Heindl  sometimes most of the time he is but its not happens on the first iteration  when the condition is true

Comment: Create a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: @charlietfl No. The code inside the interval keeps executing when it should stop

Comment: Well we have no way to run what is shown and can only guess what issue is