# Is there a way to toggle a setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am just playing around with the setInterval function in JavaScript.
I am wondering if there is a way to toggle the setInterval with an HTML button

This is my code.

```
let x = 0;
const listener = document.getElementById('listener');
const numberPlace = document.getElementById('numberPlace');

const numberCounter = setInterval(() => {
  x++;
  numberPlace.innerHTML = x;
}, 100);

listener.addEventListener('click', numberCounter);
```

The problem is that the number starts counting when the page loads and not on a button click.

Please help

Comment: Checkout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: Make `numberCounter` *a function* which when called calls `setInterval`. Currently it's the return value of calling `setInterval`…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: @thedude It doesn't.

Comment: It looks like typo problem. Just need to wrap `numberCounter` with `function () {}`

Comment: Your actual question is "how do I run code when a button is clicked", and I imagine you should be able to find existing answers that show how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) can be cancelled using [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) and the integer identifier returned when `setInterval` was called.

To toggle a `setInterval`-based counter, you simply need to toggle on the presence (or absence) of this identifier.

```js
let counter = 0;
let intervalId = null;
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const numberPlace = document.getElementById('numberPlace');

const numberCounter = () => intervalId === null
    ? intervalId = setInterval(() => numberPlace.innerHTML = ++counter, 100)
    : (clearInterval(intervalId), intervalId = null)

btn.addEventListener('click', numberCounter);
```

```html
<button id="btn">toggle</button>
<div id="numberPlace"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const numberCounter = () => setInterval(() => {
  x++;
  numberPlace.innerHTML = x;
}, 100);
```