# stop setinterval function when i hit the spacebar

Tags: javascript

I have a question, I'd like to stop the setinterval function when I hit the space bar, this script doesnt work, what is the mistake? thanks

```
window.onload = function(){
  var button=document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary')[0];
  setInterval(function(){ 
    button.click();
    if(event.keyCode == 32 ){
      return;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: you'll need to save the value returned by `setInterval` and use it in a `clearInterval` call - you'll also need an event listener to handle keyboard events

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to listen for `keyup` event, then check if the key was the spacebar, if so, you clear the interval using it's id.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary')[0];

  var intervalId = setInterval(function() { 
    button.click();
  }, 1000);

  document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32) clearInterval(intervalId)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### This is the answer:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var button=document.getElementsByClassName('btn,btn-primary')[0];
  let a=setInterval(frame, 1000);
  function frame(){ 
    button.click();
    if(event.keyCode == 32 ){
      clearInterval(a);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think something like this :

```
window.onload = function(){
  var button=document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary')[0];
  var a = setInterval(function(){ 
    button.click();
    if(event.keyCode == 32 ){
      clearInterval(a);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You didn't introduce a source for `event` variable.