# I'm trying to set an Interval inside a setInterval, but it is Accelerating

Tags: javascript

```js
var i = 0
function fill(){
    setInterval(animation,30)  // the problem starts here.
    function animation(){
        if (i<100){
            i++
            load.style.width = i+'%'
        } else {
            i = 0
        }
    }
    clearInterval(animation,30) // this should stop the interval above, but it is accelerating. Anyone nows how to solve it?
}
fill()
setInterval(fill,3000)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: clearInterval takes a number, not a callback. as written, you start a new interval every 3 seconds.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here, to be honest. Yes, `clearInterval` takes an interval ID; but have it been implemented correctly, the whole `fill` function becomes meaningless.

Comment: The argument to `clearInterval()` needs to be the value returned by `setInterval()`, not the function.

Comment: You probably want the `clearInterval()` call in the `else` block, not outside the `animation` function.

Comment: I tried to put the setInterval(animation,30) inside a var, but when I do it, it doesn't execute.
I'm a begginer at Javasctipt, I don't know how to write the code to execute it this way.

Comment: Oh, I got what I was doing wrong.
When I tried to put the 'setInterval' inside a var, it worked. But I was putting the clearInterval OUTSIDE the 'else'.
So it worked, but just the bar moved just ONE time, and I thought it was not working.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's accelerating because you don't correctly stop the previous interval. So every time you call `fill()` it adds another interval function that's updating the progress bar.

You need to save the result of `setInterval` in a variable, and use that in the `clearInterval` call.

You should call `clearInterval` when you reach the 100% limit, not immediately after calling `setInterval`.

```js
var i = 0

function fill() {
  var interval = setInterval(animation, 30) // the problem starts here.
  function animation() {
    if (i < 100) {
      i++
      load.style.width = i + '%'
    } else {
      i = 0
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }
}
fill()
setInterval(fill, 3000)
```

```css
#load {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="load"></div>
```

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you so much.
Now I have to study it so I can fully understand what was I doing wrong.
Thank you all for helping me out!

Comment: Oh, I got what I was doing wrong.
When I tried to put the 'setInterval' inside a var, it worked. But I was putting the clearInterval OUTSIDE the 'else'.
So it worked, but just the bar moved just ONE time, and I thought it was not working.
Thank you so much.