# How can I dispatch an action after every 5 min in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to dispatch an action every after 5 min. It has to dispatch action once user is logged in. It will start dispatching action every after 5min. I tried using `setInterval` but the problem here is even if  I am logout it keeps on dispatching action.

Here is My Code
I have defined this keepAlive function inside my app.js where I have wrapped whole app into redux store.
Here is `isAuthenticated` is boolean function. If `isAuthenticated` is true and `API.getAcessToken` is available in `localstorage` only then I want to dispatch action.

```
  function keepAlive() {
    if (
      props.isAuthenticated === true &&
      API.getAccessTokenFromLocalStorage()
    ) {
      setInterval(() => {
        props.keepTokenAlive();
      }, 100000); // 1000ms =1sec
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  keepAlive();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom React hook. There are libraries that solve this but the code involved is small and you could do so yourself.

For example, this is the source code from the [use-interval](https://github.com/donavon/use-interval) NPM package:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  useEffect(
    () => {
      savedCallback.current = callback;
    },
    [callback]
  );

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const handler = (...args) => savedCallback.current(...args);

      if (delay !== null) {
        const id = setInterval(handler, delay);
        return () => clearInterval(id);
      }
    },
    [delay]
  );
};

export default useInterval;
```

You would use it like so:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  useInterval(() => {
    // your code here
  }, 5000);

  return null
}
```

Comment: will it work if i put condition. like in code that i have provided in my question. I mean i only want it to dispatch action only if user is authorized .

Comment: @adityakumar just do anything you want where `// your code here`

Answer (score 2):

Can you do this?

```
let to = null;

function keepAlive() {
    //Assign a reference to clear the interval
    to = setInterval(() => {
        if (
           props.isAuthenticated === true &&
           API.getAccessTokenFromLocalStorage()
        ) {
             props.keepTokenAlive();
        } else {
            // If not passing the condition, clear the interval
            clearInterval(to);
        }            
    }, 100000); // 1000ms =1sec
}

 keepAlive();
```

Comment: yeah let me try this one

Comment: This works but this starts to give me some other issue while making first dispatch . It says isAuthenticated is undefined. But it is defined in redux store in boolean type.

Comment: Keep in mind that intervals are _paused_ when your computer goes into hibernation. Some browsers also throttle intervals when the tab is not visible/active. So "5 minutes" will not always be exactly 5 minutes.

Comment: is there any other way to handle this refresh token ? I have added this question several times here but i did not get right answer. If you know any other way can you please help me