# How to stop setinterval on a hidden element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a canvas draws an image onto it. I have added a fade in and out effect with a setinterval so it just keeps on going. I want to be able to stop this effect if the canvas is toggled to hide.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const image = new Image('naturalWidth', 'naturalHeight'); // Using optional size for image
  image.onload = drawImageActualSize; // Draw when image has loaded

  // Load an image of intrinsic size 300x227 in CSS pixels
  image.src = 'picture';

  function drawImageActualSize() {
    // Use the intrinsic size of image in CSS pixels for the canvas element
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;

    // Will draw the image as 300x227, ignoring the custom size of 60x45
    // given in the constructor
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  }
  
  //FADE EFFECT
  
$(function () {
    var effect = $('#canvas');
    setInterval(function () {
            effect.fadeIn(1000, function () {
                    effect.fadeOut(1500, function () {
                            effect.fadeIn(1500)
                    });
            });
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: Basically you set your `setInterval` to a var: `let x = setInterval(...`, then call `clearInterval(x)` to stop it

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I will try that now

Comment: marsnebulasoup. Would you mind showing me an example just tried what you said and it didnt work. I've used toggle to hide the canvas but that function still work

Comment: @ChristianKasongo - see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

So, at the top of your code, you can define an `interval` variable to store the interval in and allow it to be accessible anywhere:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const effect = $('#canvas'); // <-- you can also define `effect` here since it'll be used in both functions.
let interval = 0;
...
```

Since you want to hide and show the element, you can create two functions:

1. `hide()`, which will run only if `interval != 0`, and it will: (1) stop the interval, (2) set `interval` to 0 so we can check if it was already stopped (so you don't run the function multiple times), and (2) stop the animation and hide the canvas.
2. `show()`, which will run only if `interval == 0`, and it will: (1) unhide the canvas, (2) reset the interval.

Now, at the bottom of your code, where you create the interval, you can create the `hide` and `show` functions:

**`hide()`**

```js
const hide = () => {
  if(interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = 0;
    effect.finish().stop().hide() // finish and stop the effect, and hide the canvas
  }
}
```

**`show()`**

```js
const show = () => {
  if(!interval) { // if `interval` is equal to 0
    effect.show()
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      effect.fadeIn(1000, function () {
        effect.fadeOut(1500, function () {
          effect.fadeIn(1500)
        });
      });
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

...and, of course, call `show()` on load:

```
$(show);
```

Here's a demo:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let interval = 0;
const effect = $('#canvas');

const image = new Image('naturalWidth', 'naturalHeight'); // Using optional size for image
image.onload = drawImageActualSize; // Draw when image has loaded
// Load an image of intrinsic size 300x227 in CSS pixels
image.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/100'

function drawImageActualSize() {
  // Use the intrinsic size of image in CSS pixels for the canvas element
  canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
  canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;

  // Will draw the image as 300x227, ignoring the custom size of 60x45
  // given in the constructor
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
}
  


const show = () => {
  if(!interval) { // if `interval` is equal to 0
    effect.show()
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      effect.fadeIn(1000, function () {
        effect.fadeOut(1500, function () {
          effect.fadeIn(1500)
        });
      });
    }, 3000);
  }
}

const hide = () => {
  if(interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = 0;
    effect.finish().stop().hide() // finish and stop the effect, and hide the canvas
  }
}

$(show);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<br>
<button onclick="hide()" />Hide</button>
<button onclick="show()" />Show</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: You're most welcome. If this solved all the problems you were facing, I'd suggest [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/544203) it, so others who view this question will know it worked.

Comment: Yep. all done now and working perfectly! Again many thanks!