# Stop setInterval() after a Specific Class Becomes Visible

Tags: javascript, shopify

Currently what I'm trying to do is have a function that looks for if the **#discountbox** element is visible then clone that **#discountbox** element and place it after **.pricebox**. Right now what's happening is that it is placing it after **.pricebox** and cloning it indefinitely.

How can I get the ***setInterval*** to stop after it finds **#discountbox** and clones it once?

HTML

```
<div id="discountbox" class="discount-summary">
      You get $5 Off
</div>

<div id="modal">
    <span class="price-box">
      $20.50
    </span>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(addDiscountsummary);

function addDiscountsummary () {
if($('#discountbox').is(':visible')){  //if the container is visible on the page
      $("#discountbox").clone().insertAfter("#modal span.price-box"); //insert add to cart button after view contents buttons     
    } else {
      setInterval(addDiscountsummary, 1000); //check every 1000 ms
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. As the code is written now, it will setup multiple intervals which will never be cleared. Using `setTimeout` it will stop setting a timeout after #discountbox is visible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript

Comment: What is the event that makes the element visible? Why not use its event to insert the modal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: @Mordred I've tried using setTimeout but it results in #discountbox not being found.  #discountbox does not appear on the page on load, it appears after a couple of items are added to a cart.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for `clearInterval()` or as mentioned, a better solution would be to use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` instead

```
jQuery(document).ready(addDiscountsummary);

function addDiscountsummary () {
   if($('#discountbox').is(':visible')){  //if the container is visible on the page
      $("#discountbox").clone().insertAfter("#modal span.price-box");
      clearTimeout(window.nextTimeout);
   } else {
      window.nextTimeout = setTimeout(addDiscountsummary, 1000); //check every 1000 ms
   }
}
```

Comment: It's true this is an _alternate_ method, why do you think its a _better_ method?

Answer (score 0):

After it finds the button
Call clearInterval() method to stop your interval.

Comment: that will not work without an interval reference id

Answer (score 0):

**clearInterval(*intervalID*)** will do the trick.
When your doc loads, set the interval. Make sure the ID (which I am calling `interval`) is first created outside of any function, available to the rest of the page. When your item is found, `clearInterval(interval)`

```
let interval
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  interval = setInterval(addDiscountsummary, 1000);
});

function addDiscountsummary() {
  if ($('#discountbox').is(':visible')) {
    $("#discountbox").clone().insertAfter("#modal span.price-box");
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
var testData = !!document.getElementById("discountbox");
if(testData=="true"){clearInterval(addDiscountsummary)}
else{};
```

To your code.
This checks if the element exists in the code and returns true if the element exists:

```
var testData = !!document.getElementById("discountbox");
```

This stops the loop testData returns true.

```
if(testData=="true"){clearInterval(addDiscountsummary)}
```

Comment: This isn't correct. The function is not the interval id. The interval id has to be explicitly set and is a variable, not a method