# Stop setInterval from inside the callback function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am using `setInterval(foo, 1000);` to call a function named foo after 1 second in JavaScript.
In the function `foo` i am sending api request to check something. I want to stop the `setInterval` depending upon the response of api request in `foo`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: @Amith in the answer you suggested the setInterval is being cleared from outside the callback function in the global scope . I only want to know whether it can be cleared from inside the callback function

Comment: @AhmedAli I answered your question with that constraints, please take a look and let me know if is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) the `setInterval` returns a number that can be used with `clearInterval` in order to stop the interval.

If you store that number somewhere you can use it later inside your callback function.

For example:

```
const map = {}
const foo = () => {
    // ...your async stuff goes here
    clearInterval(map.interval)
}
map.interval = setInterval(foo, 1000)
```