# How do i clear an interval (setInterval) created with the new ES6 approach?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get this function cleared with the clearInterval but it's not working.

`setInterval( ()=>{ funca(10,3); }, 500);`

But when i use the clearInterval it doesn't stop printing the result.

Here's my code:

```
funca = function(a,b){console.log(a+b);}
setInterval( ()=>{ funca(10,3); }, 500);
clearInterval(funca);
```

It keeps printing as you can see:
[The code running in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2qYO.png)

So, how can i do it?

Comment: clearInterval takes the output of setInterval.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Comment: this "new ES6 approach" doesn't change how long established functions work

Comment: Thanks @Bravo i tought it did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` returns a value. You should use this value as the parameter to `clearInterval`:

```
funca = function(a, b){ console.log(a + b); }
const intervalHandle = setInterval(() => { funca(10, 3); }, 500);
clearInterval(intervalHandle);
```

Comment: That solved my problem thanks.