# How to stop setInterval with javasript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to start from 0. Until it reaches the numbers 709 and 54, Stop it.

**HTML**

```
<span class="card-title h5 counter"> 709 + </span>
<span class="card-title h5 counter"> 54+ </span>
```

**script.js**

```
let intervals = [];
let counter  = [];
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('counter');
Array.from(elements).forEach((element, index) => {
    counter[index] = 0;
    intervals[index] = setInterval(()=> {
            counter[index]++;
            element.innerText=counter;
        }
        , 50);
})
```

But this code goes on indefinitely and does not end.

Comment: What is currently preventing you from stopping the intervals with the interval references you save?

Comment: You need to use `clearInterval(yourInterval);` to stop the execution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way...

use the same `setInterval` for both, and clear it when there is no more counter to increment.

```js
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.counter')].map(el=>({el,counter:parseInt(el.textContent), val:-1}))

let intervalReference = setInterval(() => 
  {
  let endingCount = 0 
  elements.forEach(refs =>
    {
    if ( refs.val < refs.counter) 
      refs.el.textContent = ` ${++refs.val} + `
    else 
      ++endingCount
    })
  if (endingCount===elements.length) clearInterval(intervalReference)
  }, 50)
```

```html
  <span class="card-title h5 counter"> 709 + </span>
  <span class="card-title h5 counter"> 54+ </span>
```

Comment: I tested the speed is very low

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi the speed is depending on the delay, your computer processor, and what else.... But don't forget the Delay argument is just a minimal value, not a chronometric time

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in two separate `setInterval()` calls. Each one is defined within their own scope. This way there is no need to set up arrays for storing the values and references outside the scope:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.counter')]
.forEach(e=>{ let i=0;
  const n=parseInt(e.textContent),
     h=setInterval(()=>{
       if(i<n) e.textContent=++i +" + ";
       else    clearInterval(h);
     },20)
});
```

```html
<span class="card-title h5 counter"> 709 + </span>
<span class="card-title h5 counter"> 54 + </span>
```