# Ending clock like function in js

Tags: javascript, html

I tried implementing this clock into a polling app of sorts, problem is that whenever the host clicks a button sending the participants to a new question and starting a new clock, the old ones is still active and the webpage ends up jumping between the two eg 2->41->3->42.

How do I abort this clock with the help of a button press?

```js
var sec = 0;

function pad(val) {
  return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
}

setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = pad(++sec);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <span id="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript

Comment: `clearInterval()`

Comment: oooh ok this might have been one of my dumber questions

Comment: Also `const pad = num => String(num).padStart(2,"0");`