# Stop setInterval function with a button

Tags: javascript, function, button, setinterval, clearinterval

User have to see all bets in their dashboard so I created a a function every 2secs that loads all players bet 1 and players bet 2. I want to bind the function to a button so it will STOP running continuously when betting is close and waiting for the outcome and START the function again when the betting is open.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#load_bets1").load("loadbet1.php");
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#load_bets1").load("loadbet1.php");
    }, 2000);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#load_bets2").load("loadbet2.php");
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#load_bets2").load("loadbet2.php");
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop setInterval call in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109086/stop-setinterval-call-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval` returns an ID that can be passed to `clearInterval` to stop it.

Example to stop an interval after some time:

```js
let i = 0;
const intervalID = setInterval(() => console.log(i++), 100);
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(intervalID), 1000);
```

See also the examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval#examples.

Comment: I can use clearInterval but how can I make it run again after the betting is open again. I have a openBet button where I can put the code for restarting the function.

Comment: Run `setInterval` again, as you did initially, and store its return value.