# How do I customize the date and time displayed on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to work on the ability to customize the date and time as part of a larger project. Something like this:

```html
<body>
  <input type="date" id="date-input" placeholder="Date">
  <input type="time" id="time-input" placeholder="Time">
  <button onclick="setDateTime()">Set Date & Time</button>
  <h1>Current Date & Time:</h1>
  <span id="datetime-span"></span>
</body>
```

However, I am not sure on how I can not only display the values that I enter, but also make sure that the time entered will be updated every second/minute.

My current code looks like this:

```js
function setDateTime() {
    var dateInput = document.getElementById('date-input').value;
    var timeInput = document.getElementById('time-input').value;
    var datetimeSpan = document.getElementById('datetime-span');

    var dateTime = dateInput + ' ' + timeInput;
    datetimeSpan.textContent = dateTime;

    // Update the time every minute
    setInterval(updateDateTime, 60000);
}

function updateDateTime() {
    var dateInput = document.getElementById('date-input').value;
    var timeInput = document.getElementById('time-input').value;
    var datetimeSpan = document.getElementById('datetime-span');
    // What now?
}
```

---

UPDATE: Thanks to the help of Kiran Shahi, this problem is now solved. The Javascript is now as follows:

```js
  var runningHour;
  var runningMinute;
  var intervalId;

function setDateTime() {
  var dateInput = document.getElementById('date-input').value;
  var timeInput = document.getElementById('time-input').value;
  var datetimeSpan = document.getElementById('datetime-span');

  runningHour = timeInput.split(":")[0];
  runningMinute = timeInput.split(":")[1];

  var dateTime = dateInput + ' ' + timeInput;
  datetimeSpan.textContent = dateTime;
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  // Update the time every second, for demo purposes
  intervalId = setInterval(updateDateTime, 1000);
}

function updateDateTime() {
  var dateInput = document.getElementById('date-input').value;
  var timeInput = document.getElementById('time-input').value;
  var datetimeSpan = document.getElementById('datetime-span');

  if (runningMinute < 59) {
    runningMinute++;
  } else {
    runningMinute = 00;
    if (runningHour < 23) {
      runningHour++;
    } else {
      runningHour = 00;
    }
  }
  var paddedHour = runningHour.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  var paddedMinute = runningMinute.toString().padStart(2, '0');

  datetimeSpan.textContent = dateInput + ' ' + paddedHour + ':' + paddedMinute;
}
```

Comment: `updateTime` is not defined

Comment: thanks that was a typo, supposed to be updateDateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have implemented a rough algorithm to update the time for every second. In your case you can change it into every minute. The basic idea here is to split the time base on `:` so that we get hours and minute. And increase the minute for every second/minute you want to until its 59 otherwise reset it to 00. Similarly, incase of hour increase it unit its 23 and reset to 00 if it is 23.

I hope this solution provide you rough idea for your problem.

```js
var runningHour;
var runningMinute;
var intervalId;

function setDateTime() {
  var dateInput = document.getElementById('date-input').value;
  var timeInput = document.getElementById('time-input').value;
  var datetimeSpan = document.getElementById('datetime-span');

  runningHour = timeInput.split(":")[0];
  runningMinute = timeInput.split(":")[1];

  var dateTime = dateInput + ' ' + timeInput;
  datetimeSpan.textContent = dateTime;
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  // Update the time every second, for demo purposes
  intervalId = setInterval(updateDateTime, 1000);
}

function updateDateTime() {
  var dateInput = document.getElementById('date-input').value;
  var timeInput = document.getElementById('time-input').value;
  var datetimeSpan = document.getElementById('datetime-span');

  if (runningMinute < 59) {
    runningMinute++;
  } else {
    runningMinute = 00;
    if (runningHour < 23) {
      runningHour++;
    } else {
      runningHour = 00;
    }
  }
  var paddedHour = runningHour.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  var paddedMinute = runningMinute.toString().padStart(2, '0');

  datetimeSpan.textContent = dateInput + ' ' + paddedHour + ':' + paddedMinute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="date" id="date-input" placeholder="Date">
  <input type="time" id="time-input" placeholder="Time">
  <button onclick="setDateTime()">Set Date & Time</button>
  <h1>Current Date & Time:</h1>
  <span id="datetime-span"></span>
</body>
```

Keep in mind if you don't clear the instance of old `setInterval` before creating new instance of new `setInterval`, it will show abnormal behaviour i.e. it create multiple instances and runs in background and trigger the callback multiple times. In this case you need to hold the instance of `setInterval` and clear it before you create new instance of `setInterval`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Is there a simple way to change the displayed time from for example 23:5 to 23:05?

Comment: @Zhou yes, you can check the length of `runningHour`/`runningMinute` with `runningMinute.length` if it is 1 then append 0 infront of it when displaying in html.

Comment: Thanks. After some testing there seems to be a slight problem. The first time, when i click the button, everything is fine, however, if I click "Set Date & Time" again, then not only does +1 every second, but instead +2. The more I click, the quicker the timer becomes.

Comment: @Zhou because if you click the button multiple time then your `setInterval` executes multiple times i.e. it create multiple instances and runs in background. In this case you need to hold the instance of `setInterval` and clear it before you create new instance of `setInterval`.

Comment: @Zhou https://stackoverflow.com/a/109091/5740382

Answer (score 0):

To customize the date input to show the user, you can use the following code as a template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Styling Input Date</title>
    <!--Google Font-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <input type="date">
</body>
</html>
```

**css:**

```
*,
*:before,
*:after{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type="date"]{
    background-color: #0080ff;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-family: "Roboto Mono",monospace;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

I hope it helped you:)

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, this question was not about how to input, but rather about how to set your input as a time that is constantly changing (every second). But thank you anyway.